# sahi: How to use the escape char in javascript

Tags: javascript, char, escaping, sahi, generalized-method-of-moments

In my app i will add row and update the fields next to it. eg. as below

```
1 User1namefield 
2 User2namefield
```

for this first i need to identify label 1 and 2 and then i need to go and updated username field. 
Below code will work -

```
_setValue(_textbox("/UserName/",_near(_label("1"))),"userName1");
_setValue(_textbox("/UserName/",_near(_label("2"))),"userName2");
```

but i am writing function where i add multiple rows, and i need to generalize above code where it take $i (for loop).

How do I pass `$i` in "" quotes? I used below escape char but it is not working.

```
for(var $i=1; $i<=rows.length; $i++){
    _setValue(_textbox("/UserName/",_near(_label("\""+$i+"\"")))),"User1");
}
```

Comment: Why you need to pass it in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have a parentheses too much.

Try with: `_setValue(_textbox("/UserName/", _near(_label("\"" + $i + "\""))), "User1");`

I'm not sure why you want to escape the quotation marks, though.
If you want to convert the number to a string, this should do it:

`_setValue(_textbox("/UserName/", _near(_label($i.toString()))), "User1");`

Comment: $i.toString()  - Working thanx.

Comment: @AnandKakhandaki Could you please accept this as the answer by clicking the ckeckmark to the left?